# Unable to render a 3D model in Expo

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo

SDK Version: 37.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android/iOS.

I’m trying to load a 3D object in my application and followed many tutorials.
the model is loaded successfully and attached to scene variable but it doesn’t appear in the view.
this is a part of my graduation project and i have searched a lot the 2 months to answers
looking for a real working solution as most of the solution i found was too old and doesn’t work.

my component is as described below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { View, StyleSheet,PixelRatio ,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


import { ExpoWebGLRenderingContext, GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { Renderer, TextureLoader } from 'expo-three';
import ExpoTHREE from 'expo-three';
import * as THREE from 'three'
import {
  AmbientLight,
  BoxBufferGeometry,
  Fog,
  Mesh,
  MeshStandardMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  PointLight,
  Scene,
  SpotLight,
} from 'three';
export default class ModelScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let timeout;
        this.state= {
            loadingCompleted:true,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        THREE.suppressExpoWarnings(true)
        clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.backButton]} activeOpacity={0.8}
                    onPress= {()=>{
                        this.props.setViewModel(false);
                    }}
                >
                    <Ionicons style={styles.backButtonIcon} name="md-arrow-back"></Ionicons>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <GLView
                style={styles.viewer}
                onContextCreate={async (gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
                    const { drawingBufferWidth: width, drawingBufferHeight: height } = gl;
                    const sceneColor = '#111111';
                    const scale = PixelRatio.get();

                    // Create a WebGLRenderer without a DOM element
                    const renderer = new Renderer({gl,alpha:true});
                    renderer.capabilities.maxVertexUniforms = 52502;
                    renderer.setSize(width/scale, height/scale);
                    renderer.setPixelRatio(scale);
                    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);

                    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000);
                    camera.position.set(0, 2, 5);
                    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
            
                    const scene = new Scene();
                    scene.fog = new Fog(sceneColor, 1, 1000);
                    
                    const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0x101010);
                    scene.add(ambientLight);
            
                    const pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000, 1);
                    pointLight.position.set(0, 200, 200);
                    scene.add(pointLight);
            
                    const spotLight = new SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
                    spotLight.position.set(0, 500, 100);
                    spotLight.lookAt(scene.position);
                    scene.add(spotLight);
                    var object = null;
                    
                    const model = {
                        'thomas.obj': require('./../assets/models/thomas/thomas.obj'),
                        'thomas.mtl': require('./../assets/models/thomas/thomas.mtl'),
                        'thomas.png': require('./../assets/models/thomas/thomas.png'),
                    };
                    // Load model!
                    await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync(
                        [model['thomas.obj'], model['thomas.mtl']],
                        null,
                        name => model[name],
                    ).then((obj)=>{
                        // // Update size and position
                        ExpoTHREE.utils.scaleLongestSideToSize(obj, 5);
                        ExpoTHREE.utils.alignMesh(obj, { y: 1 });
                        // Smooth mesh
                        ExpoTHREE.utils.computeMeshNormals(obj.children[0]);
                        // Add the mesh to the scene
                        scene.add(obj.children[0]);
                    }).catch((error)=>{
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    
                    console.log(scene.children.length)
                    
                    function update() {
                        if (scene.children.length == 4)
                            scene.children[3].rotateY(0.03);
                    }
                    
                    // Setup an animation loop
                    const render = () => {
                        this.timeout = requestAnimationFrame(render);
                        update();
                        renderer.render(scene, camera);
                        gl.endFrameEXP();
                    };
                    render();
                }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
        backgroundColor:"#111111",
    },
    backButton:{
        position:'absolute',
        top:30,
        width:50,
        height:50,
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent:"center",
        borderRadius:100,
        backgroundColor:"rgb(1,175,250)",
        left:20,
        alignSelf:"flex-start",
        zIndex:10,
    },
    backButtonIcon:{
        fontSize:25,
        fontWeight:'900',
        color:"#111111",
    },
    viewer:{
        width:"80%",
        height:"80%",
    }
});
```

can anyone help me please?

## Edit

it's working now without material i have changed

`await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync([model['thomas.obj'], model['thomas.mtl']],null,name => model[name])`

to

`await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync(model['thomas.obj'],null,name => model[name])`

but it doesn't render if i load the material and don't know what's wrong with it. i tried different objects and cannot render the material. the object disappears

Comment: Maybe you need to update the view to see the model (I'm not sure that your field of view is good for your model)? Or use something like orbit controls to allow pan/zoom.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SalientBrain. i tried orbitControl and searched in the space for the model but didn't find it. i added some handy cubes generated using BoxBufferGeometry and they appear. i don't know how the model is loaded in the scene children array and don't appear. if you have any suggestions it may help

Comment: I can suggest to traverse loaded objects after scene.add(obj.children[0]). Check objects positions, scales, materials.

Comment: it's working now without material i have changed `await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync([model['thomas.obj'], model['thomas.mtl']],null,name => model[name])` to`await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync(model['thomas.obj'],null,name => model[name])` but it doesn't render if i load the material and don't know what's wrong with it. i tried different objects and cannot render the material. the object disappears

Comment: You are probably missing some assets (maybe you are fetching textures for materials from wrong paths). Check console output, try to use loader error handlers. Some materials require specific lights. If you can get materials to load (partially) - check its props to get more info.